# Close a modal after a few seconds in Blazor

Tags: modal-dialog, blazor

So basically I am want to show a modal when the user hits a button to show them if the action was successfull or if there were problems. but then after a few seconds I want to close it so the user doesn't have to manualy close it each time. Is there a way to do this without pausing the whole program for a few seconds? or is there a better way to show a user a message instead of a modal?

right now i got these 2 methods for opening and closing the modal:

```cs
    public void Open(string title, string message)
    {
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        ShowBackdrop = true;
        ModalTitle = title;
        ModalBody = message;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        ShowBackdrop = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Blazored.Toast is a great package for this : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazored.Toast/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your event/method can be async, you can skip the timer and just use `Task.Delay(milliseconds)`, something like

```
   public async Task Open(string title, string message)
    {
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        ShowBackdrop = true;
        ModalTitle = title;
        ModalBody = message;
        StateHasChanged();

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        ModalDisplay = "none";
        ModalClass = "";
        ShowBackdrop = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

So i have solved my issue and added a timer so now after i show the dialog i start a timer for 2 seconds and when that expires it executess a method that hides the modal:

```cs
    private void ToggleModal(string title, string message)
    {
        //Showing modal
        ModalDisplay = "block;";
        ModalClass = "Show";
        ShowBackdrop = true;
        ModalTitle = title;
        ModalBody = message;
        StateHasChanged();

        //Hiding modal
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 2000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        InvokeAsync(() => {
            ModalDisplay = "none";
            ModalClass = "";
            ShowBackdrop = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
```

there might be a better way to achieve this but this is what works for me for now!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a modal, I have just a div rendered on the page. This is the razor component:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
{
    <div class="alert @alertClass">@Text</div>
}


@code {
    private string messageType;
    private string alertClass = "alert-info";

    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Text = "";
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string MessageType
    {
        get { return messageType; }
        set
        {
            messageType = value;
            switch (messageType)
            {
                case "Error":
                    alertClass = "alert-danger";
                    break;
                case "Warning":
                    alertClass = "alert-warming";
                    break;
                case "Success":
                    alertClass = "alert-success";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<AlertMessage Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet." MessageType="Error"/>
```